# Purpose of self-IPI on IA-32

Tags: x86, kernel, interrupt, osdev

What is the purpose of a processor sending an Inter Processor Interrupt to itself on the IA-32 architecture?

According to the Intel IA-32 Architecture Software Developer's Manual, Vol. 3, Ch. 10.1:

> IPIs are used for software self-interrupts, interrupt forwarding, or 
>   preemptive scheduling.

But why would you use a self IPI when the processor can also interrupt itself with an INT instruction? This feature seems to be redundant.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have already known the reason since 2 years have passed.

But here's my understanding:

IPI can be blocked when IRQ is disabled, it is kept by the IOAPIC, until the destined core re-enables IRQ with an sti instruction. However an int instruction always traps the CPU into a lower ring level, no matter whether IRQ is enabled or not.

So maybe self-IPI is needed when the kernel wants to do something, but not now when the IRQ is disabled. Thus, it sends itself an IPI, making such interrupt happens as soon as the IRQ on that core is re-enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I think the big reason is consistency: If you are writing software for a multi core processor, and you want to send an interrupt out to all cores in the system, it would suck to have to do an IPI to every other core, then execute INT to interrupt the current core, and of course you will also have to setup the handlers for both interrupt sources etc... It is just much easier to send IPI to everyone.

Another scenario might be a multi core system where you are passing work or messages around to a "free" core to handle the load. The "free" core might be the current core, again you don't want to have a special case in software just because you are sending an interrupt to yourself.

Comment: Both reasons are wrong I think. Each logical processor(thus each core) has its own Local APIC. This means that a self IPI only is received by that particular core that sent it. Secondly, there is a special destination shorthand available to send an IPI to all the Local APICS in a system including itself.

Comment: Please re-read, because I only gave one reason for having self IPI (consistency) and two examples illustrating the consistency.

Answer (score 2):

There is another reason for self IPI.

If you initialize a SMI handler it's first located to a low address in ram. The entire CPU state is saved in the SMI. However, all CPUs will initially used the same state area and the new relocated address is set by manipulation of a state variable.

In this case you want to send the initial SMI to one CPU at the time. If you send it to all they will all use the same area for storing the state and that will be a disaster.

It's convenient to use the same initialization routine for SMI handler relocation for all the CPUs, so you can use the self IPI with the SMI type to enter the SMI relocation code.

The BSP can send the SMI IPI to it self and then one AP at the time. They will then one by one be relocated to non conflicting areas.

I'm sure that there are many other situations where a self IPI is needed. Whenever the CPUs shares a critical area like in the initial SMI state, the self IPI is motivated for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

No, No, No, and No.

Chris Desjardins was closest to the real reason.

I will try to shed light on the purpose of Self-IPIs. Self-IPI is indistinguishable from software interrupts (`INT nn`). Both cause a call of the specified interrupt handler through Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT). Moreover, the kernel can use both to invoke some handling procedure. But while operating system kernels tend to use Self-IPI extensively, they never use software interrupts. Why and what makes a difference? First of all, both approaches are expensive. Interrupts handling is heavy work for the CPU, which consumes hundreds of cycles. Interrupt handler prologs and epilogs perform much bookkeeping is unnecessary when both caller and callee reside in the kernel. Regular function call costs just a few CPU cycles and makes the same effect as a software interrupt. So there is not any reason to pay a hundred times more and use `INT nn`. Due to this, kernels never use software interrupts (`INT nn`) in their code. However, they still extensively use Self-IPI, which seems to do the same job. What the difference? The underlying and not evident contrast between them is that software interrupts are handled directly in the CPU core as any other instruction, but Self-IPIs are passing through Local APIC as any other hardware interrupt. While `INT nn` only mimics hardware interrupt, Self-IPI is indistinguishable from IRQ requests generated by IO devices.

And here we can find the main point: **The Local APIC implements interrupt priority schema.** It always passes to the CPU interrupt request, which has a maximal vector value from all pending ones. Interrupt requests with higher priority classes can preempt the execution of interrupt handlers for interrupt with lower priorities. In other words, the kernel can have multiple stacked interrupt handlers at the moment. Furthermore, it has a TPR register, which drains reporting of interrupts with priority lower or equal to specified. Operating systems use it so extensively that in the x64, it was aliased by the CR8 register for quicker access. In general, operating systems heavily rely on the Local APIC priority schema. For example, IRQ Levels in Windows maps directly to the Local APIC priority classes. Kernels carefully distribute vectors between interrupt sources to assign them to different priority classes and in good order. For instance, a system timer usually has the highest priority and can not be blocked or preempted by any other interrupt handler. When kernel makes Self-IPI, it requests invocation into the specified interrupt handler with accounting its priority.

Illustrative example. Windows implements the Deferred Procedure Call mechanism directly based on the Local APIC priority schema. DPC interrupt handler has the lowest priority. Using DPC, Windows implements an interrupt handling strategy similar to those in Linux and known as top half/bottom half. The top half handler runs with high priority and should be as short and as quick as possible. It delegates and defers all heavy work related to interrupt handling to the bottom half handler that runs with low priority. Similarly, in Windows, hardware interrupt handler runs with high priority and schedules DPC using Self-IPI for any heavy work. DPC, being an interrupt, runs with a priority higher than regular code (thread, processes, applications), but because it has the lowest priority, it runs when all pending hardware interrupt handlers had completed. Furthermore, while DPC execution blocks regular code, it does not block, delay, or defer execution of hardware interrupt handlers. That is true even for interrupts that arrive in the middle of DPC-procedure.